# CyanogenMod 10.2 on Galaxy S3 charging problem

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-3, charging

I have a Galaxy S3 with CM 10.2 build date 28-09-2013.

The problem I am facing is slow charging of my mobile. It takes around 6-7 hours to charge when connected to AC power source. Before CM with S3 stock rom, it used to take around 3-4 hours to charge 100%.

I tried searching on CyanogenMod forums, but couldn't get an answer on how to fix this issue. Does anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: try with a friends battery to see if your battery is broke

Answer (score 1):

Do you keep wireless or any other communication networks on while charging? This can slow down the charging process.

Comment: my cell wifi is always on. I will try disabling that while charging

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that changing the charger works in a few cases. The standard charger sometimes doesn't play nice with custom Roms.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue too from time to time, at one stage I had to turn my phone off to get a decent charge, I found that using a USB cable can slow down the charging time but as you mentioned your using a AC Power Source. How I resolved mine was buying a new battery, my battery was dated for 2012 and simply needed to go. New battery resolved my problem, and are fairly cheap!

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue. I solved it by installing boeffla kernel and turning on `ignore unstable power`.